# Converse for: If $A$ is a Normal matrix, then the field of values is the convex hull of its eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is  a Normal matrix, then the field of values of $A$ is the convex hull of the eigenvalues, that is $\mathcal{F}(A)=C_0(\sigma(A))$. What about the converse?

Book says the converse is not true, that is the following matrix is not normal but $\mathcal{F}(A)=C_0(\sigma(A)).$ To prove this consider $$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
is clear that $A$ is not normal because $AA^*\neq A^*A$ and also $\sigma(A)=\{1,i,-1,-i,0,0\}$ therefore the convex hull of the eigenvalues of $A$ is  $$C_0(\sigma(A))=\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^6\alpha_i\lambda_i:\lambda_i\in \sigma(A),\quad\sum_{i=1}^6\alpha_i=1\Big\}=\big\{\alpha_1-\alpha_2+i\alpha_3-i\alpha_4:\sum_{i=1}^6\alpha_i=1\Big\}.$$
Also if $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)^T\in \mathbb{C}^6$ then $x^*=(\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2},\overline{x_3},\overline{x_4},\overline{x_5},\overline{x_6})$ where the overline indicates complex conjugation. The definition of the field of values is $$\mathcal{F}(A)=\Big\{x^*Ax:x\in \mathbb{C}^6,\quad x^*x=1\Big\}$$ but, we can verify that $$x^*Ax=(\overline{x_1},\overline{x_2},\overline{x_3},\overline{x_4},\overline{x_5},\overline{x_6})\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_1  \\
 x_2  \\
 x_3  \\
 x_4   \\
 x_5   \\
 x_6   \\
\end{array}
\right)=x_1 \overline{x_1}+i x_2\overline{x_2}-x_3\overline{x_3}-i x_4\overline{x_4}+x_6 \overline{x_5}$$ that is $$x^*Ax=|x_1|^2+i|x_2|^2-|x_3|^2-i|x_4|^2+x_6 \overline{x_5}$$ so far so good except for that last term, is it illegal to say: let $x_6=0$?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this you arrive at $x^*Ax=(|x_1|^2-|x_3|^2-x_6\bar{x_5})+i(|x_2|^2-|x_4|^2)$

In the complex plane $(X,Y)$ the boundaries of $C_0(\sigma(A)$ are lines  $Y+X=1$, $Y+X=-1$, $Y-X=1$, $Y-X=-1$.

If $X=|x_1|^2-|x_3|^2-x_6\bar{x_5}$, $Y=|x_2|^2-|x_4|^2$ with $\sum_{i=1}^6|x_i|^2=1$ and $|x_6\bar{x_5}|\le |x_6||x_5|\le |x_6|^2+|x_5|^2$,
the combinations

$|X\pm Y|\le 1$

i let you justify this so $\mathcal{F(A)}\subset C_0(\sigma(A))$  the converse is straight if you take $x_6$ or $x_5$ equal zero.